# How do I remove file properties like 'user' and 'computer'?

Tags: windows-7, metadata

How can I remove file properties like 'user' and 'computer' in Windows 7?
I think this is 'personal information' and don't want the file to have this information when I share it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: p.s.- i am already an admin user. and the file was created by me.
p.p.s- sorry i couldn't add this to the question but i can't edit it anymore without losing the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of your screenshot, a link is shown... "remove properties and personal information", it allows you to remove that information.

Any residual owner information is not stored within the file and won't be shared when sharing your file on the internet or so. It is only used to manage permissions on your local system.

Comment: i did try the "remove properties and personal information" link. they are not editable for any file i checked.

Comment: That's because all that remains is undeletable information...

Comment: To be more precise: It’s not information that is contained within the file. Instead, this metadata is “actual” metadata. It’s similar to what you see when you `stat` a file in Linux/Unix operating systems. When you share a file, this metadata is generally not transferred, except when using special container formats (like `tar`).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the "Owner" line lists the Windows account which created that file; this information usually does not get copied anywhere outside your computer. Even when it does, only the *number* is copied, not the actual name.