# How to remove 'Owner' and 'Computer' information tag on MPG , MP4, MPEG file?

Tags: avi, mpeg, mpg

When I right click on file and go to 'Details' tab, it shows my computer name and owner name. How do I remove (hide) this information of video file (mpg, avi, mpeg).

tanks

Comment: This is a duplicate question of http://superuser.com/questions/151860/how-do-i-remove-file-properties-like-user-and-computer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove file properties like 'user' and 'computer'?](https://superuser.com/questions/151860/how-do-i-remove-file-properties-like-user-and-computer)

Answer (score 0):

What OS do you run?

I assume it is windows.

Right click, file for properties: In the bottom, there will be

"remove properties and personal information".

The you can remove information, that you don't want to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Hari does not answer the question asked.  You will need a third party application to remove owner and computer from file properties.  Windows Remove Properties dialog provides no such capability within itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1141475)